# Why the document of hoogle that generated by stack hoogle --rebuild is without base module?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hoogle

Why the document of hoogle that generated by `stack hoogle --rebuild` is without `base` module?

```yaml
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- aeson
- dns
- async
- wai
- binary
- appm
- scientific
- unordered-containers
- yaml
- text
- bytestring
- transformers
- directory
- http-client
- http-client-tls
- neat-interpolation
- filepath
- base64-bytestring
- http-types
- string-conversions
- io-streams
- time
- websockets
- network
- filepath
- HDBC
# - HDBC-sqlite3
- convertible
- QuickCheck
- parsec
- raw-strings-qq
- process
- template-haskell
- data-default-class
- uuid-types
- random
```

then i run a command `stack hoogle --rebuild` while the console output as bellow

```bash
Reordering items... 0.01s
Writing tags... 0.08s
Writing names... 0.04s
Writing types... 0.30s
Took 3.58s
Generated DB.
package base
package bytestring
package containers
package deepseq
package transformers
package text
package ghc-prim
package filepath
package template-haskell
package array
-- plus more results not shown, pass --count=20 to see more
```

But when I use `hoogle`, the results are nothing about `base` module

```
➜  api-diqye git:(main) ✗ stack hoogle hGetLine 
Specified file "ChangeLog.md" for extra-source-files does not exist
Minimum version is hoogle-5.0. Found acceptable hoogle-5.0.18.3 in your index, requiring its installation.
Data.ListLike hGetLine :: ListLikeIO full item => Handle -> IO full
Data.ListLike.IO hGetLine :: ListLikeIO full item => Handle -> IO full
```

Expecting of `hGetLine :: Handle -> String` from `base` module appearing

Comment: The documentation for `base` and other boot libraries may be in a different location, associated with the GHC version. I'd still expect `stack hoogle` to find it, so it might be a bug.